# document.evaluate on body node returns element out of body

Tags: javascript, xpath

I'm currently using the following line of code to retrieve all the text nodes in the "body" element of a page:

```
document.evaluate("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']", document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

However, even though I specify "document.body" as the context node, I get some element contained in the "head" of the page.

How am I supposed to use "document.evaluate" to narrow it down to the body element without having to do it in the XPath query? (I guess it's possible as it seems to be the goal of the second argument)

Comment: Try to use `.//text()` instead of `//text()`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks !